# Make borderless window behaves alwaysontop [Autohotkey]

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create a borderless window, but alwaysontop didn't work if the window is borderless, how to make borderless window behave alwaysontop ?

```
gui, Tool: add, button, x0 y0 h20 w140 gxub, TOOLS
gui, Tool: show, w150, TOOLS
WinGet, id1, ID, A       ; GET ahk_id of active window 
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A ; hide title bar
Winset, Alwaysontop, ON, ahk_id %id1%
```

Comment: 1) Why use `WinSet` if `Gui` provides that functionality, too? 2) Have you tried setting it always on top before you remove the title bar?

Comment: Here are some good examples of GUI without borders: http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3851 Maybe it can also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding one line on the top will satisfy your need

```
gui, +alwaysontop
```